# Gap between Edittext underline and Hint in Input Layout

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

I am using `EditText` Input layout.

**Below is my xml code :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want to give more gap between the `editText` underline and the `hint text`(Enter Password). And I want to reduce the size of the `hint text`.

Can anyone please help me how to get this.

[image]

Comment: Use padding in `TextInputLayout1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code : Use `android:padding="any value in sp/dp"` for between your bottom line and editText.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:translationY="3dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set padding for gap between the edittext underline and hint text and use this for changing hint size:

```
<string name="hint"><font size="20">Hint!</font></string>
```

example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: The most clever way to change the size of the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try using paddingTop with translationY property of EditText. For example

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_edittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Password"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:translationY="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this!!

**For Space**

Give `padding` to **EditText** as much as you want

**For text size**

In **style.xml**

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

In your **layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:clipChildren="false"
     app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:translationY="3dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```